# Windows access to files

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

How can I find out which file is copying by windows or windows is trying to access? How can I restrict it? I want my program monitor these activities and respond...

Comment: You need to write a low level driver. Effectively you are writing a virus scanner. You won't be able to do that with Delphi. At least the kernel mode parts can't be done with Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the various directory and file change notifcations, see here for more details as it's not a simple topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx